# What does it mean when lsmod list a module with -1?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

We all know that 'lsmod' lists out loaded modules in linux kernel.

I'm working on a kernel module and creating two threads inside it. Due to some bugs it's getting crash as soon as I'm loading it into system.

So I started debugging it, I tried to unload module using "rmmod", after that when ran 'lsmod' in terminal I got something like:

```
# lsmod
Module       Size      Used by
kthread      16438     -1
```

As much I know, Used by shows the list of modules dependent on this module but unable to find any proper information why I'm getting "-1" and what does it mean.
Any clue of suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably there is a bug in `kthread` module

Comment: yes, bug is there and I'm debugging it. But I want to know what does it mean having "-1" in used by.

Comment: It is just a number. It's your code's duty to manage the number, your code can inc/dec it by any arbitrary number.

Comment: Looks like a reference counting bug: one ref and two unrefs.

Comment: I was able to replicate this problem on my Acer C720 (Ubuntu 16 LTS). My trackpad died (a rare but notable problem) and I tried modprobe -r i2c_designware_pci and it hung... opening another terminal and doing lsmod now shows -1 dependencies for i2c_designware_pci.   It seems like the number of dependencies is changed BEFORE the kernel module fails/succeeds in being removed so if it hangs its still dropped.